# What is this song effect called?

Tags: rock, pop

I noticed some songs having this effect<sup>1</sup>, almost always rock/pop ones: A singer just finishes singing a verse, and meanwhile a (the same or another one) singer starts singing another one.

This effect is especially visible in this song: [Bon Jovi - This house is not on sale](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ri2KEiXlNk), for example at this point (between the boldened verses):

> [chorus]
>   [...]
>   Where memories live and the dream don't fail.
>   **This house is not for sale.
>
>   Coming ho-o-o-o-ome,**
>   coming home.
>   [...]

What is this effect<sup>1</sup> called?

---

<sup>1</sup>: I'm calling it an 'effect' because I don't know how else to call it. Feel free to edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(For future readers, the example cited by the OP begins at around the [0:52](https://youtu.be/_Ri2KEiXlNk?t=53s) mark, though it returns throughout the song.)

When I first read your question, my immediate thought was **elision**. This term, taken from linguistics, basically suggests an overlap of two thoughts. As one thought ends, either the next thought has already begun or it begins at *precisely the same moment* that the previous thought ended.

With that said, Bon Jovi actually finishes "not for sale" about halfway through the measure (the "and" of beat two) and the back-up singers begin "Coming home" on beat 4, so they don't actually overlap.

Thus, this seems to just be normative practice, and I don't think there's a special term for it. One thing ends, and another thing begins...business as usual!

But in the case of overlap (which might be what you're thinking of), I would call it **elision**.